# How to clear stucking error in Visual Studio Code in PHP editor?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Some PHP errors are 'sticking' in Visual Studio Code though the code is already correct and it runs on server without errors. Adding/deleting lines or some code doesn't help. There is no option to refresh. Error is persistent and is highlighted in the editor by curved red line. It's annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround:** change the language and select it back.
Stuck error mysteriously will disappear.